# Money Market, LM curve, starting with a change in Interest Rate

Tags: macroeconomics, open-economy-macro

Consider

$$r=r^*+\theta$$

where $r$ is the domestic interest rate, $r^*$ is world interest rate, and $\theta$ is a risk premium and/or expectation rate adjustment.

The economy is small and open, which means there is perfect foreign capital inflow/outflow, and $r$ has no effect on $r^*$.

**Shock**: there is an expectation of appreciation of the domestic currency in the world markets; nominal exchange rate is expected to rise.

**Question**: describe the short-run effects on this economy's Money Market and LM curves (short-run means $P$ level is constant and $\left(\dfrac{\bar M}{\bar P}\right)^s$ is constant)

**My answer**:

$\theta$ decreases, so $r$ decreases

In the Keyensian Cross, lower $r$ leads to increased $I(r)$, so $PE$ shifts upward.

In the IS-LM, this corresponds to a rightward shift in IS curve

Here is the part where I start getting very confused....

**Money Market**: a decrease in $r$ means that the $OC$ of holding money goes down, so it seems to me there should be an increased demand for money, or liquidity preference, at all levels of income.

Does this mean that $L(r,\bar Y)$ shifts to the right?  This seems like the correct intuition, yet if $L$ shifts rightward with $\left(\dfrac{\bar M}{\bar P}\right)^s$ constant, the equilibrium interest rate is higher, not lower.

How would the money market adjust in this scenario, and what would the corresponding change of the LM curve look like in the IS-LM?